# How to find out to use best flow in IdentityServer?

Tags: identityserver4

How to find out the best flow for each applications types?

e.g:

1. for web apps : asp.net mvc, php?
2. for web apps : SPA (angular, react,…)
3. for mobile apps : android, ios
4. and for desktop apps?

is there any decision flowchart for that?

Comment: A quick Google search for OpenId Connect (OIDC) flows produces some good articles that you should consider, such as https://medium.com/@robert.broeckelmann/when-to-use-which-oauth2-grants-and-oidc-flows-ec6a5c00d864 and https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use either the **authorization code flow** where users are involved or the **client credential flow** for machine to machine communication.

All other flows has been deprecated, take a look at the [OAuth 2.1](https://oauth.net/2.1/) specification for guidance.

Btw, [OAuth 2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-00) was just approved and you can hear all about it in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUEBatNmsbY)

Comment: But what about hybrid flow?

Comment: I think you should only focus on authorization code flow with PKCE and client credential flow.